# What causes: Xcode "No such module 'exp_lib' error for my pure swift app's statement: "import exp_lib"?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Created static lib Swift project exp_lib and built its exp_lib.a file.
Created Swift app and dragged in .a file.
Put .a is in Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries
I put absolute path to .a in Build Settings > Library Search Paths
In ViewController, I put "import exp_lib" and get the error.

I tried Frameworks Search Path.
I tried dragging .a to Proj nav and to Link Binary With Libraries.
Started from scratch (ie. new projects).

What am I missing?
Should "import" statement have project name or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was because I failed to add the .swiftmodule to the app and I didn't set Swift Compiler - Search Paths > Import Paths.

1. .swiftmodule file must be in same folder as .a file.
   ie. In swift app project, do Xcode command to add files and select *BOTH* .a and .swiftmodule files.
2. Build Settings > "Search Paths" > Swift Compiler - Search Paths > Import Paths: must have path to .a's folder.